# Does independence imply d-separation?

Tags: bayesian, independence, bayesian-network, artificial-intelligence

In the context of Bayesian networks **if** two random variables (*i.e.* nodes) are d-separated, they are independent. However, is there any example of random variables being independent but not d-separated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does statistical independence mean lack of causation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357255/does-statistical-independence-mean-lack-of-causation)

Comment: I think this question is worth leaving open, but the link by @usεr11852 is *well* worth the read.

Comment: @Alexis: I retracted my vote.

Answer (score 3):

**The *No* answer:** Variables that are d-separated are always independent, and variables that are independent are d-separated. D-separation is a concept formalized by Pearl to understand association from the perspective of a causal DAG. The 'independence' you ask about is the language of statistics describing *the same* concept of association under different formalisms.

D-separation on a causal DAG, and statistical independence are both describing the same lack of association, so it is not possible to have statistical independence among d-connected variables.

**The *Yes* answer:** The comment by usεr11852 touches on the issue of *faithfulness*: there *may* be a zero measure of *average causal effect* (ACE), even if the sharp causal null hypothesis is false. For example, if (1) $A$ causes $Y$ (both dichotomous) because for some individuals $Y^{a=1}\ne Y^{a=0}$, but in some individuals $Y^{a=1} - Y^{a=0} = 1$ and in others $Y^{a=1} - Y^{a=0} = -1$ and (2) the number of individuals in each group is the same, then although there are individual causal effects, the ACE is zero, and the measure of association is *unfaithful* because $A$ & $Y$ are *not* d-separated.

See Chapter 6: Graphical Representations of Causal Effects (especially Fine Points 6.1 and 6.2) in Hernán, M. & Robins, J. (2019; forthcoming) [*Causal Inference*](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/). Boca Raton: Chapman & Hall/CRC