# Mix of terms causation and dependence in 'book of why'?

Tags: causality, causal-diagram

In the 'book of why' he says:

> the listening pattern prescribed by the paths of the causal model
> usually results in observable patterns or dependencies in the data

I don't understand, why he says "usually". Isn't it **always** the case when we have causation that we shall see some sort of dependence in the data?

Then, I really can't follow why he says this:

> "There is no path connecting D and L" which translates to a
> statistical statement "D and L are independent".

Correct me if wrong, but the absence of a path only means **there is no causation**... Why he says D and L are independent? I mean, both D and L can be highly correlated and still we could see no path connecting D and L.

Both quotes are from page 13.

Comment: For the first part, maybe the case of offsetting/cancelling effects is relevant. It is rarely plausible but not technically impossible.

Comment: There's a distinction between *path* and *directed path*, where the latter must follow the direction of causality (arrows), and the former does not.  And it sounds like you're thinking of "directed path."  So $X \leftarrow Z \rightarrow Y$, says $X$ and $Y$ are both are caused by $Z$.  $X$ and $Y$ might be correlated, but neither causes the other.  There is no directed path between them, but there is a path between them (since they have a shared cause).  Does that help?

Comment: Also remember that the lack of an arrow between two variables in a DAG means **no *direct* causal effect**, not **no causal effect**. For example, in the DAG $A \to B \to C$, $A$ is for sure a cause of $C$, even though it is not a *direct* cause of $C$.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't understand, why he says "usually". Isn't it always the case
> when we have causation that we shall see some sort of dependence in
> the data?

No, because you can have accidental cancellations. See here for an example: [Does statistical independence mean lack of causation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357255/does-statistical-independence-mean-lack-of-causation/357275#357275)

> Correct me if wrong, but the absence of a path only means there is no
> causation... Why he says D and L are independent?

You are conflating a directed path with paths in general. Paths do not need to be causal. For instance, consider a third variable $Z$. If $Z$ is a common cause, we have the path $D \leftarrow Z \rightarrow L$ and this induces a non causal association between $D$ and $L$. We call such paths ``back-door'' paths.  This is a path very much like $D \rightarrow L$ is a path.

So when we say ``absence of paths,'' we mean a complete absence of any connection between the two variables in the DAG, directly or indirectly. If there are no paths from $D$ to $L$, be it direct or indirect paths this indeed implies independence between the two variables.

Comment: +1 Was going to answer with the link you provided if no else had. :D There is a great example of an automobile's speed and the angle of the accelerator pedal that I am trying to remember a source for that would also be a good example (it is pretty similar to the boat example Dimitriy quoted). :)

Answer (score 4):

This only addresses your first question, but I wanted to point out that cancellation does not have to be *accidental*. It can be the outcome of purposeful human behavior. This is a key point to me since that implies cancellation (and sign-flipping of the correlation) is the norm rather than a once-in-a-very-blue-moon event.

This example is taken from Scott Cunningham's [Causal Inference: The Mixtape](https://mixtape.scunning.com/index.html).

[image]

> But weirdly enough, sometimes there are causal relationships between
> two things and yet no observable correlation. Now that is definitely
> strange. How can one thing cause another thing without any discernible
> correlation between the two things? Consider this example, which is
> illustrated in Figure 1.1. A sailor is sailing her boat across the
> lake on a windy day. As the wind blows, she counters by turning the
> rudder in such a way so as to exactly offset the force of the wind.
> Back and forth she moves the rudder, yet the boat follows a straight
> line across the lake. A kindhearted yet naive person with no knowledge
> of wind or boats might look at this woman and say, “Someone get this
> sailor a new rudder! Hers is broken!” He thinks this because he cannot
> see any relationship between the movement of the rudder and the
> direction of the boat.
>
> But does the fact that he cannot see the relationship mean there isn’t
> one? Just because there is no observable relationship does not mean
> there is no causal one. Imagine that instead of perfectly countering
> the wind by turning the rudder, she had instead flipped a coin—heads
> she turns the rudder left, tails she turns the rudder right. What do
> you think this man would have seen if she was sailing her boat
> according to coin flips? If she randomly moved the rudder on a windy
> day, then he would see a sailor zigzagging across the lake. Why would
> he see the relationship if the movement were randomized but not be
> able to see it otherwise? Because the sailor is endogenously moving
> the rudder in response to the unobserved wind. And as such, the
> relationship between the rudder and the boat’s direction is
> canceled—even though there is a causal relationship between the two.
>
> This sounds like a silly example, but in fact there are more serious
> versions of it. Consider a central bank reading tea leaves to discern
> when a recessionary wave is forming. Seeing evidence that a recession
> is emerging, the bank enters into open-market operations, buying bonds
> and pumping liquidity into the economy. Insofar as these actions are
> done optimally, these open-market operations will show no relationship
> whatsoever with actual output. In fact, in the ideal, banks may engage
> in aggressive trading in order to stop a recession, and we would be
> unable to see any evidence that it was working even though it was!
>
> Human beings engaging in optimal behavior are the main reason
> correlations almost never reveal causal relationships, because rarely
> are human beings acting randomly. And as we will see, it is the
> presence of randomness that is crucial for identifying causal effect.

Comment: Great excerpt! Is there a technical term for this phenomenon? Searching for "cancelation" in this context doesn't seem to bring up much.

Comment: Endogeneity is the term used in economics. The standard example is the estimation of supply and demand curves.

Comment: +1 Wish I could give you more, 'cause we need more art. :D